# how to change the style of the font programmatically in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uifont

I would like to change the style of the font (like bold, regular, light, oblique) programmatically. I know I can use the IB, but I would like to change it using programmatically. Need some guidance on this. Sorry if it is a stupid question.

For example, my code looks like this:

```
lblAge.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20];
```

I would like to add the style which is regular in. How do I it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should get you going

```
offerTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT" size:14.0f];//here offerTitle is the instance of `UILabel`
```

Hope this helps:)

Comment: @lakesh: Dalee's answer is correct. And here you can find a list of possibilities: http://iosfonts.com/

Comment: like the example in my question, I would like to make it regular style

Comment: For Helvetica familiy you have this options: Helvetica, Helvetica-Bold, Helvetica-BoldOblique, Helvetica-Light, Helvetica-LightOblique, Helvetica-Oblique

Comment: @ lakesh hope this helps and fits in your need:)

Answer (score 5):

Try this solution:

```
myLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f];
myLabel.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:16.0f];
```

For regular size:

```
myLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: is there any for regular size?

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 8.2 and above there is [`+ systemFontOfSize:weight:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/systemFontOfSize:weight:) which allows you to specify weighted system fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Look at API of UIFont. Assign created font to the property 'font' of designated object

```
oneLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithXXX];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static NSString *_myCustomFontName;
+ (NSString *)myCustomFontName:(NSString*)fontName{

    if ( !_myCustomFontName ){
        NSArray *arr = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:fontName];
        // I know I only have one font in this family
        if ( [arr count] > 0 )
            _myCustomFontName = arr[0];
    }
    return _myCustomFontName;
}
```